# I need to know how to add images from a files on my windows 10 PC to a google apps script HTML website

Tags: image, google-apps-script

I want to add images to a google apps script hosted webpage.

I tried looking around the menus and checking google.

I want it to display the image at the desired size

Comment: You can host it somewhere and use `<image src ="image.yourhost.com"></image>`

Answer (score 0):

## Images from Albums in my Google Photo Library in a Web App

```
function doGet(e){
  return displayAlbums(true);
}

//used for web app and dialog depending upon weather web parameter is true or not.  If it's not provided then it's false. 
function displayAlbums(web) {
  var web=web||false;
  //different color backgrounds for each album
  var bgA=['#f3eeb3','#f3e2b3','#f3ceb3','#f3b3b6','#f3b3b6','#f3b3ef','#b3eaf3','#b3f3e3','#b3f3cb','#bdf3b3']
  var html='';
  var n=0;
  var albumsA=listAlbums();
  for(var i=0;i<albumsA.length;i++) {
    html+='<html><head></head><body>';
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<div id="d-%s" style="margin:auto;max-width:500px;background-color:%s;">',i,bgA[i]);
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<h1>%s</h1>', albumsA[i].title);
    var images=listImagesOfAnAlbum(albumsA[i].id);
    for(var j=0;j<images.length;j++) {
      html+=Utilities.formatString('<br />%s - %s<br /><img src="%s" width="500" />',j+1,images[j].filename, images[j].baseUrl);
    }
    html+='</div></body></html>';
  }
  if(!web) {
    var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(600).setHeight(500);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Displaying my Albums');
  }else{
    var output=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(600).setHeight(500);
    return output.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL).addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=360, initial-scale=1');
  }
}

function listAlbums() {
  var token=null;
  var fA=[];
  var n=0;
  do{
    var params = {muteHttpExceptions:true,headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
    var url=Utilities.formatString('https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/albums?pageSize=50%s',(token!=null)?"&pageToken=" + token:"");
    var resp=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params);
    var js=JSON.parse(resp.getContentText());
    for(var i=0;i<js.albums.length;i++) {
      fA.push({id:js.albums[i].id,title:js.albums[i].title,count:js.albums.mediaItemsCount});
    }
    token=js.nextPageToken;
  }while(token!=null);
  Logger.log(fA);
  return fA;
}

function listImagesOfAnAlbum(albumId) {
  var albumId= albumId || 'Default Id for debugging';
  var token=null;
  var iA=[];
  var n=0;
  do{
    var params = {
      method:"post",
      muteHttpExceptions:true,
      headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      payload:{"albumId": albumId,"pageSize":"50","pageToken":token}};
    var url="https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:search";
    var resp=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params);
    var js=JSON.parse(resp.getContentText());
    for(var i=0;i<js.mediaItems.length;i++) {
      iA.push({filename:js.mediaItems[i].filename,baseUrl:js.mediaItems[i].baseUrl});
    }
    token=js.nextPageToken;
  }while(token!=null);
  return iA;
}
```

[Google Photos API](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/get-started)

I added this to the manifest file:

```
"exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
```

Also adding this to your google scripts even though you don't need it will provoke the authenticator to added the need scopes.  And also setup the Drive API in Resources Advanced Google Services.

```
//DriveApp.getFiles();
function listFiles() {
  var files = Drive.Files.list({
    fields: 'nextPageToken, items(id, title)',
    maxResults: 10
  }).items;
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    Logger.log('\n%s-Title: %s Id: %s',i+1,file.title,file.id);
  }
}
```

> This is a technique describe by Bruce McPherson as borrowing a Token you can read about it [here](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/goa)
>
> I had already loaded the Oauth2 and GOA libraries. According the Mr. McPherson you will need to install the GOA Library although I never actively used it.  He has a walk through [here](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/goa/walkthroughs/useappsscript) Just go through his little slide presentation.  This may seem like a lot of trouble and it is.  But it does provide you with programmatic access to the photo library.  Fortunately, Google does all this for us on most of our libraries.

**From Your Personal Computer to your Website with DataURI's**

Another way to get images right off of your Google Drive and into your webapp website.

[image]

The Javascript in the `<script>` tags of your website:

```
         google.script.run
         .withSuccessHandler(function(iObj){
           console.log(iObj);
           for(var i=0;i<iObj.iA.length;i++) {
             if(i==iObj.iA.length-1) {
               $('#header').css('background-image','URL(' + iObj[iObj.iA[i]] + ')');
             }else{
               $('#' + iObj.iA[i]).attr('src',iObj[iObj.iA[i]]);
             }
           }
         })
         .getSimpleSiteImages();
        });
```

The Google Apps Script:

```
function getSimpleSiteImages() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('SimpleSite');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var oObj={iA:[]};
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    oObj.iA[i]=vA[i][2];
    oObj[oObj.iA[i]]=getDataURI(vA[i][1]);
  }
  return oObj;
}

function getDataURI(fileId) {
  var file=DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  return file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
}
```

The Google Apps Script That Makes the DataURI:

```
function convImageUrl(url){
  var blob=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  var b64Url='data:' + blob.getContentType() + ';base64,' + Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes());
  return b64Url;
}
```

Just save on your google drive and upload them into your images.